# CUDA doesn't work as expected?

Tags: c, cuda

I have programmed CUDA code.

```
unsigned long mask_buffer;
int s;
off_t p,

for(p=0;p!=5000;p++)
{
    for(s=start;s!=end;s++)
    {
        ref_off = *(((unsigned int*)(idx_base)) + p);

        if((int)(first_indexes[s-start_sequence] % 8 - ref_off % 8) < 0)
        {
            int shamt2 = (ref_off % 8 - first_indexes[s-start_sequence] % 8);
            mask_buffer = *((unsigned long *)(msk_base + (ref_off - first_indexes[s-start_sequence])/8)) >> shamt2;

            if( ( (*(unsigned long *)(seqmaskc + 16 * (s-start_sequence))) ^ mask_buffer ) << shamt2) 
                continue;
        }

        else if((int)(first_indexes[s-start_sequence] % 8 - ref_off % 8) == 0)
        {
            mask_buffer = *((unsigned long *)(msk_base + (ref_off)/8));

            if( (*(unsigned long *)(seqmaskc + 16 * (s-start_sequence)) ^ mask_buffer))
                continue;
        }

        else
        {
            int shamt2 = 8 - (first_indexes[s-start_sequence] % 8 - ref_off % 8);
            mask_buffer = *((unsigned long *)(msk_base + (ref_off/8- first_indexes[s-start_sequence]/8) - 1)) >> shamt2;

            if( ( (*(unsigned long *)(seqmaskc + 16 * (s-start_sequence))) ^ mask_buffer ) << shamt2) 
                continue;
        }

        int shamt = (ref_off % 4 - first_indexes[s-start_sequence] % 4) * 2;

        memcpy(reference_blk, ref_base + ref_off / 4 - first_indexes[s-start_sequence] / 4, sequence_bytes);

        for (rp = last_rp ; rp != (unsigned long *) reference_blk ; rp--) 
        {
            unsigned long tmp = ((*rp) & ((1 << shamt) - 1)) << (8 * sizeof(unsigned long) - shamt);
            *rp = (*rp >> shamt) | shifted_in;
            shifted_in = tmp;
        }

        *rp = (*rp >> shamt) | shifted_in;

        if (sequence_length & 0x3)
            reference_blk[sequence_length >> 2] &= (1 << ((sequence_length & 0x3) << 1)) - 1;

        for ( i = sequence_length >> 2 ; i & (SEQUENCE_ALIGN - 1) ; i++ )
            reference_blk[i] = 0;

        //-- instead of memcmp --//
        int v = 0;
        char *p1 = (char *)sequence;
        char *p2 = (char *)reference_blk;
        int tmp_asd = sequence_bytes;

        while(tmp_asd!=0)
        {
            v = *(p1++) - *(p2++);

            if(v!=0)
                break;

            tmp_asd--;
        }

        if(v == 0)
        {
            mat_count[s - (int)start_sequence]++;      /* Maintain count */
            mat_position[s - (int)start_sequence] = ref_off-first_indexes[s-start_sequence]; /* Record latest position */
        }

    }
}
```

This for loop is main function of my code.
But the problem is that variable "p" is never increased over 5 or 6.
I have GT530 in my computer and my CUDA Driver Version and Runtime Version are also 4.0.
What is problem in this code???

Comment: Could you include the full code, or at least the part of the code with types in it?

Comment: Without more context, I don't think we can provide very much help. Is it possible for you to paste more of your code?

Comment: Is this the kernel code? Seems to be host code. Also, what should your function do? What do you expect? How can we tell you what is wrong without knowing the expected behavior? Your code is not self explanatory either, so to know what you expect is essential.

Comment: My code wants to find some special string in the huge size of data. For example, I want to find "aa" in huge size of string like "aabdcdegvdfaa...". And variable "p" is increased.  So, variable "reference_blk " is converted "aa", next "ab", "bd" like this. Finally , we can find "aa" from first to end. But, the variable "p"is not increased over 5 or 6. So I cannot find all "aa". this is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is indeed a kernel, which your original post before your new code edit claimed it was, you can't call standard C-library functions like `memcpy` inside of a CUDA kernel (you do that about half-way through the code).  You can only call `__device__` functions in a kernel.  So unless that is a re-implementation of `memcpy` in CUDA, calling that function inside your kernel is not going to work ...

Also, if you are going to attempt to write CUDA kernels that need to check the results of what other threads in the group have written, such as you're doing in the memory comparison section of your kernel, you will need to place some synchronization points in your code in order to ensure that all the threads have reached a certain point before you start checking the results from those threads.  If you are attempting to check what another block may have written to  main memory, there are also synchronization primitives for that as well that ensure that the results of any previous thread block have been written out to main memory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, my program is not final version yet. So I tried run this code with 1 block and 1 thread like sequential version. The synchronization problem is very important problem, but more important problem now is the correctness problem I think. And I try to convert memcpy to another method.

Comment: BTW, are you on Windows or Linux? If I recall correctly, at least on earlier versions of CUDA, like 2.x, you can't run a Windows CUDA kernel for more 5 seconds due to a Windows display driver timeout if the card you're running the CUDA kernel on also has the Windows desktop extended onto it ... so if you're running on a single thread, then you might be running into this limit depending on the size of your string.